# USB ports fried? How to diagnose/fix?

Tags: usb, xubuntu, diagnostic

i've just run into a probably serious problem.

Was working on a hardware project where a short circuited component was involved and it's possible i've fried two usb ports with a 12V on my laptop since when i connect the mouse or my phone they don't work as they should, however my phone thinks like it's connected to a charger.

What happened: Connected that component to one of the two usb 3.0 ports on the laptop and as soon as i connected the power, laptop immediately shut down obviously protecting itself.

Afterwards, booted up normally but those two ports won't work as before.

Restarted many times etc, but still nothing. Mouse won't work and the phone thinks it's connected to a charger instead of a computer, so there's still some current running there.

ran this:

> dmesg | grep -i USB

but couldn't detect any "movement" in those two usb ports.

So, how do i know if USB ports can be revived? I could only found various instructions in Windows but nothing in Ubuntu. Is there something i can do in general?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like hardware damage. I don't think anything via software will fix this if you tried to connect something that is 12V to a 5V USB port.